# if statement dealing with boolean variable

Tags: java

I want my if statement to print out student or non student based on a boolean variable isStudent but I am not quite sure how it works. When I enter boolean isStudent it automatically initializes the variable false? And when I try to use isStudent == true nothing prints out but if I use isStudent == false it prints out student and non student. Can someone explain why it does that and if I did this right?

```
   public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean isStudent = false;
            if(isStudent == false){
                System.out.println("Student");
                System.out.println("non-student");
            }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: google it - Java If else example

Comment: `isStudent` is `false` because you set it as `false`. So of course `isStudent == false` is true.

Comment: Please don't downvote a question for it being obvious. Downvote it if it's not well-written etc.

Answer (score 5):

When you have this code:

```
if(isStudent == false){
   System.out.println("Student");
   System.out.println("non-student");
}
```

Everything inside the curly braces { } is executed if the condition is true. You want an `else` statement

```
if (isStudent){
  System.out.println("Student");
} else {
  System.out.println("non-student");
}
```

Comment: Plus one, being able to gauge your answer to the experience of the OP is a talent.

Answer (score 3):

what you are looking for is called an else statement it would look like this

```
 public class Test {   
public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean isStudent = false;
            if(isStudent)
            {
                System.out.println("Student"); 
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("non-student");
            }
        }   
    }
```

heres another way without else since you asked but not a preferable way.you make a default string and declare it as a non student and it will only change if it is a student.

```
 public class Test {   
public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean isStudent = false;
        String student = "non-student";
            if(isStudent)
            {
                student = "Student"; 
            }
            System.out.println(student);

        }   
    }
```

this might help
[if-else](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/if_else_statement_in_java.htm)

Comment: Appreciate the help but would there be way to do this without an else statement?

Comment: You *could* write `if (!isStudent)` in place of the `else` but why would you want to do that?

Comment: Oh I see was wondering if there an easier and faster way but the else statement is much more convenient

Comment: I edited the above to add in a non else way but the else is the best option and they are used a lot in programming languages. Another thing you could look into are switch statements.

Comment: Oh I didn't think there was a way! Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

`isStudent == false` is no more than a *logical negation*: it's equivalent to `!isStudent`.

The clearest way you can write what you want to do is

```
if (isStudent /* == true is implicit*/){
    System.out.println("Student");
} else /*all other possibilities*/{
    System.out.println("non-student");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After the below statement, the value of `isStudent` is `false`.

```
boolean isStudent = false;
```

In the next step you are checking if `isStudent` is equal to `false`.. which is true and the statements inside the block (`{...}`) will be executed, which prints the strings..

```
 if(isStudent == false){
```

Also, default value of boolean variable is false.

Answer (score 0):

Also instead of using:

```
if(isStudent == false)
```

you could also do:

```
if(!isStudent)
```